# Android: Missing BR when doing databinding

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding

Why does the BR object not generated when I do the databinding? I have seen it once but when I start a bit more of coding it's not generated

Comment: You should post code so we can see what went wrong. If your class extends BaseObservable and each field has a getter denoted with the @Bindable expression, then the databinding plugin should generated a BR.* for that getter.

Comment: I forgot to post my fixes.. I closed the android studio and reopen it again it works fine.

Comment: It happens to me all the time. Only File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart solves it for me...